# Facebook Connect issue with the iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

I have to integrate FaceBook connect with the iPhone App. 
I downloaded SDK, added new app on the facebook.

But I have a problem. All samples and tutorials contains feature with feeds publishing. 
In the sample which included in the SDK I have to insert Template Bundle Id instead of `'9999999'`:

```
- (void)publishFeed:(id)target {
  FBFeedDialog* dialog = [[[FBFeedDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
  dialog.delegate = self;
  dialog.templateBundleId = 9999999;
  dialog.templateData = @"{\"key1\": \"value1\"}";
  [dialog show];
}
```

Where can I create templateBundleId? I can't found how to create it in the Developer's Tools.

May be templates is deprecated. If it's true then what can I use for publishing on the FB? And how can I do it with the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You create the templateBundleId in the console - http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php

Comment: I can't found it in the console! 
Console contains API Test Console, FBML Test Console and Facebook Connect Playground only. 
Where can I create templateBundleId?